# how to get absolute path of a different server

Tags: asp-classic, absolute-path, multiple-domains

We have hosted some downloadable files on our different server due to bandwidth problem.
Now we want to download those files using an ASP script from our current server.

But how could we know the absolute path of that particular server using ASP script ?

regards
sk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure of what you're asking...

If the remote files are within a website on the remote server, you van reference them directly. If they are managed within your application, you may need to build some additional web service/httphandler or "asp" page that retrieves and serves the image (binary write, setting mime type etc)

Comment: hi

some downloadable files hosted on a server with IP (100.100.100.100)

An asp script running on say http://mydomain/example.asp

with this example.asp we want to download files hosted on (100.100.100.100) server.

here we are facing problem to get the absolute path of (100.100.100.100).

please help.

regards

sunny